# what if first client request for a read and second client for write operation in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

will the parallelism Follows both the clients be able to read and write same time at the file ?
What if both Client tries to create the new file with the same name ?

Answer (score 0):

HDFS follow Write once Read many models.

To write a file in HDFS, a client needs to interact with master i.e. namenode (master). Now namenode provides the address of the datanodes (slaves) on which client will start writing the data.

To read a file from HDFS, a client needs to interact with namenode (master) as namenode is the centerpiece of Hadoop cluster (it stores all the metadata i.e. data about the data). Now namenode checks for required privileges, if the client has sufficient privileges then namenode provides the address of the slaves where a file is stored. Now client will interact directly with the respective datanodes to read the data blocks.

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Site your sources https://data-flair.training/blogs/hadoop-hdfs-data-read-and-write-operations/

Comment: whatever i read further hadoop follow Write once ,read many so if first client is writing the second is only able to read ,may be he will not see updated data .

Comment: hadoop follows write once read many model so how data can be updated when it written once